Statistical test for unequal sample sizes of repeated measures (non-parametric)
I'm looking to understand the differences between various sources (50) that evaluate an event based on 8 ordinal scales (varying from 2 to 4 values) associated with a discrete score between 0 and 10, with steps of 0.1. There are approximately 250k events. A few sources have evaluated almost all the events, whereas the rest have sparse evaluations. I aim to understand the following: (1) independence between the sources, (2) which scales are independent, and (3) which scales drive the differences in agreement on the discrete score.
Thoughts for (1): I initially thought of using a Wilcoxon-signed rank test for each pair of sources and subsetting to those that have evaluated the same events, then looking at how many sources are independent based on that. However, that doesn't answer the second and third questions. I also feel like comparing each pair seems incorrect, but I'm not sure. I know that using a Friedman test doesn't work, as most of the sources are sparse.
Thoughts for (2): I guess I would treat the sources as random effects, but I'm unsure what test to use.
Thoughts for (3): If I had just two sources, I would do an ordinal regression comparing the differences for each event between the two sources, with the score as the dependent variable, but I'm not sure how that would work for multiple sources.
So my questions are:

Is the Wilcoxon-signed approach for answering (1)?
What is a good approach to answer (2)?
What is a good approach for (3)?

